# Extracting Tables from PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-to-html

I want to extract Tables in a `PDF` document pro-grammatically using C# for a college project. i'm quite familiar with `itextsharp`.

1. Is there a way i can extract tables in `itextsharp` ?
2. Is there any other free library i can use for this purpose ?
3. Can i convert the `PDF` to XML/HTML in order to extract `<table>` tags, if so is there a free library i can use for `PDF` to HTML conversion ?

   or

please give me a suitable solution for this..

Comment: have you looked at `ITextSharp's` documentation/examples they have on their site..?

Comment: yes, so far i couldn't find a way to do this in itextsharp because tables are mostly text data.we can't differentiate table data from text data in itextsharp.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this and extend what you need from this example I converted from VB.Net to the C# equiv

```
public static string GetTextFromPDF(string PdfFileName)
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileName);
    dynamic sOut = string.Empty;

    for (i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        sOut += iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i, its);
    }
    return sOut;
}
```

Comment: textextractionstrategy is for extracting text from the pdf document.yes the code works fine for that purpose,but i need to extact the table.how can i identify the text inside the table except other paragraph text ?